# Parallelize iterative calculation using Theano

Tags: python, performance, optimization, parallel-processing, theano

This is a piece of python code that basically just calculates the activations of a neural network and then updates the new state for the next input value `data[t]` with respect to an arbitrary leaking rate `a`.

```
x = zeros((resSize,1))

for t in range(trainLen):
    u = data[t]

    xUpd = tanh( dot( Win, vstack((1,u)) ) + dot( W, x ) )
    x = (1-a) * x + a * xUpd 

    X[:,t] = vstack((1,u,x))[:,0]
```

It is not that important to understand what this is exactly doing. My question is: Can I parallelize this using the GPU with `Theano`? You can see that the new `x` depends on the previous value of `x` so what I would want to do is to parrallelize the calculations for those vectors and matrices. If those arrays become considerably large this will result in a much better performance.

Could anybody tell me how to do this?

Comment: I don't understand why this was marked as off-topic. I can answer this question. I'm the lead Theano developer and I can tell it have enough information for me to answer. So I'll answer in a second comment bellow.

Comment: My answer is generic and apply to all system, not just Theano. As each iteration of your loop depend on the previous one, you can't paralelize your iterations completly. You could parallelize the `u=data[t]` as it don't depend on the previous x. You could parallelize `dot( Win, vstack((1,u)) )` for the same reason. But you can't parallelize `dot(W,x)` and what depend on it like tanh and the lines afters.

Comment: If you want to optimize this, you can move outside the loop all computation that don't depend on x. This will allow to work with more data at the same time and so could be faster. So the dot(win, ...) could be speed up. But this will raise the memory usage.

Comment: @nouiz Thanks for your answer. Now I see. You are right, so basically I could parrallelize `dot( Win, vstack((1,u)) )` by using a large matrix for all temporary results and then use it for the calculuation. I've voted for *reopen*. If it gets reopened I can mark your answer.

Comment: Where can you vote to reopen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ticket was closed as off-topick, so I answered it in the comment. So here my answer as a post.

My answer is generic and apply to all system, not just Theano. As each iteration of your loop depend on the previous one, you can't paralelize your iterations completly. You could parallelize the `u=data[t]` as it don't depend on the previous x. You could parallelize `dot( Win, vstack((1,u)) )` for the same reason. But you can't parallelize `dot(W,x)` and what depend on it like tanh and the lines afters.

If you want to optimize this, you can move outside the loop all computation that don't depend on x. This will allow to work with more data at the same time and so could be faster. So the `dot(win, ...)` could be speed up. But this will raise the memory usage.